# How to loop queue checking code?

Tags: bash, scripting, queue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disconnect modem when postfix queue empty](https://serverfault.com/questions/328549/disconnect-modem-when-postfix-queue-empty)

This script code checks to see if the postfix mail queue empty and if true it disconnects my modem.

```
#!/bin/sh
postqueue -p|grep empty
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  killall wvdial
fi
```

I need to run it many times as needed until the mail queue gets empty.

How can I loop it?

Maybe placing an **else** that returns to execute the script from the line of **postqueue -p|grep empty** ?

I know it can be simple but am not too much expert in bash scripting so I need help to complete this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! postqueue -p | grep -q empty; do
    sleep 1
done
killall wvdial
```

Comment: wow!! just what i needed! it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
while postqueue -p | grep -q empty; do
    killall wvdial
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Yes Kevin, this seems to be very similar to the answer of Juaco, both of your codes fix my script, now it works perfectly as i want. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code works even better (as it is faster on large queues):

```
while [ `find /var/spool/postfix/{deferred,active,maildrop}/ -type f | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; do
    sleep 5
done
killall wvdial
```

And note that this question is a duplicate of your [own question](https://serverfault.com/questions/328549/disconnect-modem-when-postfix-queue-empty).

Comment: Yes, but you probably need more privileges to look in this folders (deferred,active,maildrop). But to speed the find up, you may use `-print -quit` to get only the first match

`while [ \`find /var/spool/postfix/{deferred,active,maildrop}/ -type f -print -quit\` != "" ]`